# I need a word like "cinematic universe" but for books/literature

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to name a book "The Cow ____ Universe", but I don't know the word for it.

Comment: What's wrong with "The Cow Universe"?

Comment: You want synonyms for the corpus of cow literature?

Comment: Why wouldn't *genre* work?

Comment: The Cow's Literary Universe

Comment: Wikipedia uses [fictional universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_universes_in_literature) as a more general term but you should explain what you mean and what context you're working in, rather than assuming we're all MCU fans and everything is an exact copy of the MCU (this isn't Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange). Is the Cow Universe your own creation or are you writing about existing books? Why do you need to have the term in the title? Read the [guidance for single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: You could use "The Matter of Cow" analogous to "The Matter of Britain" or "The Matter of France".

Answer (score 1):

**[Literary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literary)**

> of, relating to, or having the characteristics of humane learning or literature

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literary)

Compare to [cinematic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cinematic).

> of, relating to, suggestive of, or suitable for motion pictures or the filming of motion pictures

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cinematic)

Answer (score 0):

Mythos?

From Wiktionary, defn 2: "A story or **set of stories** relevant to or having a significant truth or meaning for a particular culture, religion, society, or other group; a myth, a mythology." (emphasis mine)